7.1 Audio option disappears and re-appears seemingly at random
Sound occasionally stops working, so I made a script that configures things the way I like after restarting pulseaudio.
It includes the following two lines:
pactl set-card-profile alsa_card.pci-0000_10_00.1 output:hdmi-surround71
pactl set-sink-volume alsa_output.pci-0000_10_00.1.hdmi-surround71 40%

That works most of the time, but sometimes it returns
Failure: No such entity
Failed to get sink information: No such entity

My script that fixes Pulseaudio starts with
pkill pulseaudio
rm ~/.config/pulse/*
sleep 1s
systemctl --user daemon-reload
systemctl --user restart pulseaudio

Is there anything else I could add to have it rediscover the 7.1 profile?
Currently the only solution is to wait until it re-appears by itself and then run the script again.
System Info
$ uname -a
Linux sand 5.15.0-105-generic #115-Ubuntu SMP Mon Apr 15 09:52:04 UTC 2024 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

$ cat /etc/upstream-release/lsb-release
DISTRIB_ID=Ubuntu
DISTRIB_RELEASE=22.04
DISTRIB_CODENAME=jammy
DISTRIB_DESCRIPTION="Ubuntu Jammy Jellyfish"

$ sudo lshw -C display
  *-display                 
   description: VGA compatible controller
   product: Navi 22 [Radeon RX 6700/6700 XT / 6800M]
   vendor: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI]
   physical id: 0
   bus info: pci@0000:10:00.0
   logical name: /dev/fb0
   version: c5
   width: 64 bits
   clock: 33MHz
   capabilities: pm pciexpress msi vga_controller bus_master cap_list rom fb
   configuration: depth=32 driver=amdgpu latency=0 resolution=1920,1080
   resources: irq:86 memory:e0000000-efffffff memory:f0000000-f01fffff ioport:f000(size=256) memory:fd700000-fd7fffff memory:c0000-dffff


What fixes this issue somewhat reliably for me is the following.
# Turn off the desired sink
pactl set-card-profile alsa_card.pci-0000_10_00.1 off

# Turn on some other sink
pactl set-card-profile alsa_card.pci-0000_12_00.3 output:analog-stereo

# Turn off the other sink (I set it to input only)
pactl set-card-profile alsa_card.pci-0000_12_00.3 input:analog-stereo

# Turn on the desired sink
pactl set-card-profile alsa_card.pci-0000_10_00.1 output:hdmi-surround71

